# Modifying a specific.custom-checkbox

Tags: css, html, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm running Prestashop 1.7 and am using it's freely available GDPR compliance module, which i've hooked into the newsletter .tpl. All of the checkboxes are defined by the .custom-checkbox input ID. If I edit this one, every checkbox on the website changes it's colors.

Hence, what I'm trying to achieve is, modifying the checkbox that is used by the class gdpr_module_16.

I'd like to modify a specific `.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox]+span`

```
 .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + span .checkbox-checked {
    display: none;
    margin: -.25rem -.125rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: #232323;
}
```

The html structure looks like this:

```
<div id="gdpr_consent" class="gdpr_module_16">
<span class="custom-checkbox">
    <label class="psgdpr_consent_message">
        <input id="psgdpr_consent_checkbox_16" name="psgdpr_consent_checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
        <span><i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked psgdpr_consent_icon"></i></span>
        <span>Dummytext dummy dummy</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

And the one that I want to address pops up in the firefox dev tool if I select

```
<i class="material-icons rtl-no-flip checkbox-checked psgdpr_consent_icon"><div></div></i>
```

I've tried to address it via

```
.custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox]+span .gdpr_module_16 .psgdpr_consent_checkbox

.custom-checkbox input .gdpr_module_16 .psgdpr_consent_checkbox

.gdpr_module_16 .psgdpr_consent_checkbox .custom-checkbox input[type=checkbox]+span
```

and

```
.gdpr_module_16 .psgdpr_consent_checkbox .custom-checkbox
```

My

```
border-color:white;
```

hasn't workt with any of them.

Comment: You could give it an ID or another class and apply the style rules to that, or use a child selector to select that specific child to apply rules to it. Could you post a snippet with your HTML and CSS?

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more clear in your question then. Let us know what you want to achieve, what you're using, what your limitations are, etc.